# PHP Open FTP XML Feed and Save On Another Server

Tags: php, xml, cron

I would kindly like to know if anyone has a simple PHP script which I can run as a cron to basically open a XML file from a URL I have (on a different server) and re-save in a directory on my own server.

The URL is a FTP URL with a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
file_put_contents(file_get_contents('ftp://user:password@remoteserver.com/file.xml'), '/path/to/new.xml');
```